# set data in repeater from component

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I created a repeater field in October CMS and I want to set data from frontEnd.
I created a  (form) component but I do not know how to set my form's data in the repeater.

has anyone experience like my problem?

Comment: created a repeater field in October CMS => `where exactly`,  and and `where you are showing repeater field`. so we get better idea

Answer (score 0):

**the value saved in database is of a repeater field is in json array.**

so for your solution, you need to save a repeater field from backend and then go to database table to check how it is saved in json array.

now you just need to make a similar type of array **( and don't json encode it because october model will do this for you )** from your front end form component and save it.